# can't find Workflow Process Definition by webdav url using core-service

Tags: 2013, core-service

I am trying to look up a Workflow Process Definition by webdav url. I have looked up one by tcm-id, and it tells me its webdav url is: /webdav/Publish%20Bundle%20Workflow but when I try to load it, it can't be found. I consulted the docs to see what extension I should be using:
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_11BA56D2F9064F19BEFDCFEEC5C49220
but there is no extension listed for Process Definition. What extension should I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the WebDAV URL given for a Process Definition is just `/webdav/<Escaped Process Definition Title>` and that trying to read a Process Definition by that URL reports "No items found".

An alternative to using a WebDAV URL to find your Process Definition without relying on the Tcm Id is to use something like the following Core Service code:

```
var publicationId = "tcm:0-79-1";
var processDefinitionTitle = "Task Process";

var processDefinitionsFilter = new ProcessDefinitionsFilterData() {
    ContextRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData() {
        IdRef = publicationId
    }
};
var processes = client.GetSystemWideList(processDefinitionsFilter);
var process = processes.Where(p => p.Title == processDefinitionTitle).First();
```

That should get you an IdentifiableObjectData for your Process Definition.

Comment: thanks. yes... I had sort of stumbled upon that approach and didn't get around to posting the result.

Answer (score 4):

As I know - process Definition doesn't have WebDav Url. 
Not sure, why loading with webDavUrl flags returns something.